# Two arrays with different length in a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays with different length, and I need to use them in the same loop.

This is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
data=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
data1=`date -d "1 day" +%Y-%m-%d`
cd /home/test/em_real/

#first array (today and tomorrow) 
days="$data $data1"
#second array (00 till 23)
hours="00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23"

for value in $hours
do

cp /home/test/em_real/mps_"${days[i++]}"_"$value":00:00 /home/DOMAINS/test_case/
sleep 10
done
```

Tt fails, doesn't get days.

How can I do it?

@fedorqui If now, inside the bucle, I want to remove the dash (-) of days and do another order, I don't know why it doesn't get the string , the code is the following:

```
days=("$data" "$data1")   #create an array properly

for value in {00..23}; do
for day in "${days[@]}"; do
cp "/path/mps_${day}_${value}:00:00" /another/path/test_case/
d=d01
hourSIMULATION=01
clean= echo ${day} | sed -e 's/-//g'
sed -e 's/<domine>/'$d'/g' -e 's/<data-initial>/'$clean$value'/g' -e 's/<hour-SIMULATION>/'$hourSIMULATION'/g' run_prhours > run_pr
done
done
```

The string `$dayclean` is empty when I check inside `run_pr`, do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf it doesn' work with ${day}clean .... I have modified the name of the string, dayclean for clean...and it doesn't again get the value...in this case.. clean should be 20151101... and inside the file run_pr  $clean is empty..

Comment: again, `clean` is never set! you probably want `clean=$(echo ${day} | sed -e 's/-//g')`. But wait, don't do it that way, use parameter expansions instead: `clean=${day//-}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thank you it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `days[i++]` but no `i` is defined anywhere. Not sure what you want to do with `${days[i++]}` but `$days` is just a string containing `"$data $data1"`.

You probably want to say `days=($data $data1)` to create an array.

Also, you can say `for hour in {00.23}` instead of being explicit on the numbers.

Then, you want to loop through the hours and then through the days. For this, use a nested loop:

```
days=("$data" "$data1")   #create an array properly

for value in {00..23}; do
   for day in "${days[@]}"; do
      cp "/path/mps_${day}_${value}:00:00" /another/path/test_case/
   done
done
```